# Sort file in SFTP based on datetime using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, posh-ssh

I have multiple files in the SFTP folder that were created at the same time but at different dates in their filenames.
Example file:

```
REGISTRATION_ELI_20210422_071008.csv 
REGISTRATION_ELI_20210421_071303.csv
REGISTRATION_ELI_20210420_071104.csv
```

I want to copy 1 file with today's date in its filename and send it to local. Which property can I use to list files and copy the one that matches today's date?

```
#Setting credentials for the user account
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("gomgom", $password)

$SFTPSession = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName 172.16.xxx.xxx -Credential $Credential -AcceptKey

# Set local file path and SFTP path
$LocalPath = "D:\WORK\Task - Script\20221010 - AJK - ITPRODIS380 - upload file csv ke sql server\csvfile"
$SftpPath = '/Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI_*.csv'
    
Get-SFTPItem -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionID -Path $SftpPath -Destination $LocalPath | Sort-Object {[datetime] ($_.BaseName -replace '^.+_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}) (\d{2})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:')  } | Select-Object Name
    
Remove-SFTPSession $SFTPSession -Verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change your $SftpPath like this :

```
$SftpPath = "/Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI$([datetime]::Now.toString('yyyyMMdd'))_*.csv"
```

I introduce the date in he path you look for :

```
/Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI20221221_*.csv
```

---

You can perhaps solve your problem by first listing remote files and them download the one you want by date. I don't test but it gi can give something like that :

```
$SftpPath = '/Home Credit/Upload'
$SftpPath = "/Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI$([datetime]::Now.toString('yyyyMMdd'))_*.csv"
$Files = (Get-SFTPChildItem -SessionId $Session.SessionId -Path "$SftpPath") | where {$_.name -like $SftpPath}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
  Get-SFTPItem -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionID -Path $file -Destination $LocalPath
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I've tried, and it worked for one of part.

`$SftpPath = "/Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI_$([datetime]::Now.toString('yyyyMMdd'))_*.csv"

 $SftpPath`.

The output: /Home Credit/Upload**/REGISTRATION_ELI_20221221_.*csv.**

There is one part missing in the file name REGISTRATION_ELI_20210422_**071008**.csv.

How about this?

Comment: If you keep a sta (*)  it will get all the file for today's date, whatever exists in this place.

Comment: No, I get error like this: Path **/Home Credit/Upload/REGISTRATION_ELI_20221221_*.csv**  does not exist on the target host.

Comment: You can solve your problem by first listing remote file and them downloading the one you want by date.